# What would present day society be like if people were much more intelligent on average

Tags: science-fiction, alternate-history, dystopia

My earlier question was closed because I didn't follow the rules properly. Truly sorry about that. I hope I'll do better this time.

My question is, what would a society be like today if people had evolved a much higher intelligence than we actually did. Let's say our average would be at their bottom.

To narrow things down, since the question is so broad, I'll add a few areas that might or might not be affected by a higher average intelligence and you can focus on those in your answer:

Science/Technology
Religion
Political ideology
Morality
Please feel free to define intelligence in whatever way you like.

Comment: Pedantic: 100 is *by definition* "average" IQ. You are really asking about all humans having *the equivalent* of what would be *in our world* 200 IQ.

Comment: Thanks, Matthew! You're of course correct! :)

Comment: No change, except that everyone would be strangely skilled at solving analogies and word puzzles.

Comment: @FranklinPezzutiDyer: Or maybe we'd more high quality corssword puzzles. Anyway, you are right; raw intelligence has never been the main limitation of human development.

Comment: (1) There is no overpopulation to solve. Earth is still mostly uninhabited. (2) Eugenics doesn't work, because it's operation spans centuries whereas its goals are always linked to the momentary ideological fads of the day. (3) National-socialist Germany did medical experimentation on the disadvantaged. Communist Russia did it. Capitalist America did it. (4) Why do you think that intelligent people are cowards who would trade freedom for illusory safety? (5) We already use technology to survey and control the population. (6) Society *is* divided into human resources and Very Important Persons.

Comment: Welcome to [worldbuilding.se]! Please note that our [help/dont-ask] states that "To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where ... your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers." No problem as you're new here, but please be aware of this for the future.

Comment: Also, please be aware that Stack Exchange is not a discussion forum. Your title question is very broad (you want us to consider everything about all societies across the globe?) and the body of your post is, frankly, an invitation to a discussion. SE's model is one-specific-question/one-best-answer. What, exactly, do you need help with?

Comment: @Matthew Very true - in fact, the "average IQ" has indeed gone up over the past century, but the mean is always normalized back to 100. The average person today would have an IQ of 130 by the standards of 1910. We are *already living* in a society of high-IQ individuals, comparable to the past. See the Flynn Effect.

Comment: Voted to close. There are some awesome answers here to even one of the 20 sub-questions in the original question. I feel like, unless the question is broken down into smaller questions, it's going to be very challenging to do it justice.

Comment: Sadly you question is still closed even after edition, but, remember it reading [this](https://www.discovermagazine.com/planet-earth/the-human-brain-has-been-getting-smaller-since-the-stone-age)

Answer (score 2):

**Everyone would either be a robot or a psychopath**

You see, iq doenst really mean anything. IQ is just the basic skills needed to function in society.

[Most iq tests](https://www.quora.com/Why-so-do-many-people-report-IQs-exceeding-160-when-almost-no-serious-IQ-tests-have-a-ceiling-thats-over-160-165) have a ceiling of around four standard deviations. The [original](https://www.iqmindware.com/iq-mindware/how-to-do-a-raven-matrices-test/) progressive  matrices tests were just following directions.

> 1. Constant in a row. This is ‘rule 3’ in the matrix example above – the orientation of the bar is the same in each row, but changes down a column.

> 2. Quantitative progression. An increase or decrease between adjacent entries in size, position or number.

> 3. Figure addition or subtraction.  A figure from one column is added to or subtracted from another column to produce the third. An example is given below:

And so on.

The modern iq tests have become increasingly subjective (and [approached as a deep learning problem](https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.01646)), rather than just a normal test where you follow directions.

The vocabulary IQ tests are still meaningful, in that they have clear, categorical solutions. But again, this is simply following directions, and anyone can ace these tests if they understand what they are supposed to be doing.

A verbal IQ above the 140-160 ceiling is not possible, because there are not enough words to test for and once you understand all of them there is no higher score. Verbal IQ is socially determined because it is based on other people's accepted meanings of words, and if you know every word, there is no way to even test for more.

A fluid IQ above this ceiling is conceivable if you write a more advanced test that has more complex instructions, that more people fail- therefore increasing the difficulty and raising the maximal standard deviation score possible. However, this becomes meaningless after a point because it only tests for a trivial, procedural type of intelligence that computers are capable of anyway. Although your 200 iq society would have a lot of people able to understand parking meters, buy coffee, and have the basic cognitive skills that IQ implies, after that point IQ lacks practical value.

If an organism is so specialized in pattern matching and following directions then they lose unique human abilities. For example, [humans employ fuzzy logic](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/235333084_Fuzzy_logic_between_human_reasoning_and_artificial_intelligence) to randomize their actions. A functioning human *will not* get a high iq score because not following directions is a human trait.

So all the benefits you mentioned might happen- but only because those humans would be limited to simple procedural logic. Ignoring physical reality, and assuming that humans can pack unlimited iq into their brains, we can assume this doesnt happen and move on.

[IQ and Machiavellianism](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.psypost.org/2018/10/evil-geniuses-people-high-in-machiavellianism-may-have-superior-reasoning-abilities-52240/amp)

One of the downsides of high iq is increased machiavellianism. If you are so much smarter than everyone around you then there is a tendency to take advantage of them. Since your question is about a society with high iq- not just individuals- then this might apply less if other people can see through your tricks. But nonetheless, [higher iq allows more sophisticated forms of criminal behavior](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3262063/), even if it reduces overt violent crime.

**Economic growth and innovation would be the least important result**

The resource consumption and population growth that makes growth possible might actually be less appealing to higher IQ people. Because [geography is the main reason iq correlates with growth](https://ideas.repec.org/p/unm/unumer/2013056.html), simply making people smarter will not increase capital accumulation or availability of resources. In fact, it wont make much of a difference at all. [IQ also apparently reduces fertility](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S016028961000005X), so lower population growth would reduce the need to grow the economy. Also, as a sidenote, some of the highest IQ nations like China and Singapore are not democracies- so its more complex than "more iq means more democracy". Singapore  also has [pretty high inequality](https://www.onlinecitizenasia.com/2019/07/05/the-problem-with-singapores-inequality-denialism-2/), so the IQ-inequality relationship is not linear either.

**[Religion, intelligence, and autism](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10943-019-00926-3)**

The link between [religious belief and intelligence](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4175010/) also seems complex. It is possible that early life experiences correlate with belief and intelligence, but once people have "made up their mind" there isnt a relationship. There are reasons for religion besides belief, such as social affiliation, so there isnt a strong correlation. IQ probably reduces certain aspects of religion but it doesnt eliminate it.

> We found that religious belief, but not attendance, was negatively related to intelligence

Furthermore,

> An analysis of the specialized abilities on which the religious and non-religious groups differ reveals no clear pattern. We cautiously suggest that this may be explicable in terms of autism spectrum disorder traits among people with high IQ scores, because such traits are negatively associated with religiousness.

It may not be that iq reduces religiosity, but that mainstream religion is replaced by dogmatic autistic beliefs.

In short, iq is just a basic bar for functioning in society. Beyond that bar, IQ becomes correlated with other factors that often lead to negative results. If IQ is meant as a test of how to be a good person, then test for those traits, because IQ by itself is a test taking skill.

**The computation-temperature tradeoff**

[As a sidenote](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs42514-019-00011-x), the difference between human and machine intelligence has a physical basis. Temperature/desynchronization/nondeterminism increase when you pack more computation into a small space. Low temperature, non deterministic, parallel processing contradicts high temperature, exact, serial processing. Humans are essentially parrots- see a situation, run it through past situations, and output what you know- just on a large scale.

Computers rely less on storage of past situations and more on accurately processing new instructions, so computers will always outscore human type intelligence. Computers are more like a [middle tier](https://www.yourdictionary.com/middle-tier#:%7E:text=middle%20tier%20-%20Computer%20Definition,or%20step%20between%20two%20others.), human intelligence is more like layers of SQL joins that happen over and over again that are hard to serialized and work better in parallel. Fluid IQ tests test for computer like intelligence.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there were no other changes than IQ scores, not much would change. Many of the problems society experiences aren't the result of a deficit of intelligence among our species, and that's assuming that IQ tests measure intelligence in a meaningful way.

It's unclear exactly what they do measure. Paradoxical phenomena like the Flynn effects are very real, but the explanations for that (and the others) aren't agreed upon.

Furthermore, while it might not be a bad assumption that with a much larger population of intelligent people that we'd see some exponential increase in scientific and engineering breakthroughs (largely due to the network effect... two geniuses will give you more than twice the rate of having one genius because they collaborate with each other and are essentially greater than the sum of the parts), most scientific processes are limited today by organizational and funding issues. A brilliant rocket scientist should be working at NASA after all (or some agency much like it), but what do you do when there are 200 of them? NASA won't get x200 funding in such a scenario. And so on.

Some of your examples are just a misunderstanding of what IQ (and intelligence) even mean. One can be exceptionally intelligent and remain superstitious. One can be superstitious and perfectly aware of how absurd it is. Humans don't have unitary minds after all. Impulsivity? Why would that be different? There's not a single spectrum here of impulsive on one side, and intelligent on the other.

And overpopulation? The world likely is suffering from a nearly-opposite problem. Fertility rates are far below replacement levels in many places, in those places where they aren't they're dropping on the same curve we've seen (just lagging), and fertility rates never recover once they fall below replacement.

Answer (score 1):

**Uncomfortable.**

I am thinking of border collies.  The smartest of dogs.  They will figure things out.  They need to figure things out, and work the world, and think.

They are good dogs as sidekicks if you are doing outside work.  They are less good for holding down the rug and barking at the mailman and getting pets.  You don't need such a smart dog for that.  A smart dog that is bored will figure out jobs for itself, and cause trouble.

So too with humans?  Maybe it is for the best that everyone is not super smart.

As regards a society entirely comprised of "Alphas"; from [Brave New World](https://archive.org/stream/ost-english-brave_new_world_aldous_huxley/Brave_New_World_Aldous_Huxley_djvu.txt)

> Each one of us, of course," the Controller meditatively continued,
> "goes through life inside a bottle. But if we happen to be Alphas,
> our bottles are, relatively speaking, enormous. We should suffer
> acutely if we were confined in a narrower space. You cannot pour
> upper-caste champagne surrogate into lower-caste bottles. It's obvious
> theoretically. But it has also been proved in actual practice.  The
> result of the Cyprus experiment was convincing."
>
> "What was that?" asked the Savage.
>
> Mustapha Mond smiled. "Well, you can call it an experiment in rebot-
> tling if you like. It began in A.F. 473. The Controllers had the
> island of  Cyprus cleared of all its existing inhabitants and
> re-colonized with a  specially prepared batch of twenty-two thousand
> Alphas. All agricultural and industrial equipment was handed over
> to them and they were  left to manage their own affairs. The result
> exactly fulfilled all the  theoretical predictions. The land wasn't
> properly worked; there were  strikes in all the factories; the laws
> were set at naught, orders disobeyed; all the people detailed for a
> spell of low-grade work were perpetually intriguing for high-grade
> jobs, and all the people with high-  grade jobs were
> counter-intriguing at all costs to stay where they  were. Within six
> years they were having a first-class civil war. When  nineteen out of
> the twenty-two thousand had been killed, the survivors  unanimously
> petitioned the World Controllers to resume the government of the
> island. Which they did. And that was the end of the only  society of
> Alphas that the world has ever seen."

Comment: This was my first thought after read the question! (=